# How to fix unity package manager errors?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, package, assets, metafile

I use unity 2022.1.21f1. I wanted to add the urp package to my project with package manager but in the console there was a lot of errors. I also tried to add other packages but situation is the same. Errors said "script has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored". How can I fix this?

I tried to delete plugin's folders from MyProject/Library/PackageCache. I tried to reinstall package.

Comment: Try to start a new project from scratch and add your packages there. Something seems to be off with your current project.

Comment: Thanks for advice but nothing changed. The new project have errors in plugins which I successfully installed to the previous project. It looks like something wrong with package manager.

Comment: Which Unity version are you using?

Comment: I have wrote this above. I use 2022.1.21f1.

Comment: I suggest you try the latest LTS version 2021.3.16f1

Comment: Thanks! It is working now. I just update version to 2021.3.16f1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I understood 2022.1.21f1 is not stable. The solution is quite simple. I just updated unity to 2021.3.16f1.

Comment: I suggest you report this bug to Unity devs